# Only use $in operator if a certain condition is met - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, query-string

Okay so this is probably just me being stupid and not having looked through the MongoDB docs properly but anyway **here's the deal**:

I have a RESTful API route which looks like this:

```
GET /api/users?ids[]=id1&ids[]=id2
```

Which gets parsed into an object that looks like this:

```
var parsedObject = {ids: ['id1', 'id2']}
```

This returns the users with the specified ids from the query string. Now, I want this to be optional so a request like this could also be valid:

```
GET /api/users
```

In mongoose, in order to find the users with the specified ids (if any), I need to use the `$in` operator when querying as follows:

```
UserSchema.find()
  .where('_id').in(req.query.ids)
  .exec(function(err, users){
    //some code
  });
```

However, when `req.query.ids` doesn't exist, instead of returning all documents, it returns nothing.

I have already tried stuff like this:

```
var queryIds = req.query.ids || {};
```

How can I use `$in` only if `req.query.ids` exists? Surely there must be a better way than doing something like this:

```
if (req.query.ids) {
  UserSchema.find()
    .where('_id').in(req.query.ids)
    .exec(function(err, users){
      //some code
    });
} else {
  UserSchema.find()
    .exec(function(err, users){
      //some code
    });
}
```

I hope this makes sense... Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of:

```
var queryIds = req.query.ids || {};
```

try this:

```
var queryIds = req.query.ids || [];
```

because it should be an array and not an object.

But most likely you will have to do a conditional query, maybe something like this:

```
UserSchema.find(req.query.ids ? {_id: {$in: req.query.ids}} : {})
    .exec(function(err, users){
      //some code
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the conditional query seems to have done it!